# Simple heaviside function graphic with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I basically want [this](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtb/4/txe3ba4l.htm) (first diagram) done with gnuplot. I've searched and found nothing exactly like this. I can do a good heaviside without the little circles at the end and start of the two lines, but I can't seem to get it with the little circles. Actually, the second diagram would be nice to know too. The third too, but I'm not greedy.

Comment: Does any of the suggestions answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the records and completeness... although you can define a function

```
H(x) = x<0 ? 0 : 1
```

If you plot

```
plot H(x) w l
```

the line will be continuous at zero and of course without points.
So, another suggestion with just two columns x,y and variable pointtype would be the following.

**Code:**

```
### Heaviside function
reset session

$Heaviside <<EOD
-2 0
 0 0
 
 0 0.5
 
 0 1
 2 1
EOD

set yrange [-1:2]
set ytics 1
unset key
set multiplot layout 3,1
    plot $Heaviside u 1:2 w l lc 0, \
         '' u 1:($0==1||$0==3?$2:NaN):($0==3?7:6) w p pt var lc 0

    plot $Heaviside u 1:2 w l lc 0, \
        '' u 1:($0==1||$0==2||$0==3?$2:NaN):($0==2?7:6) w p pt var lc 0

    set xrange [0:4]
    a = 3
    plot $Heaviside u ($1+a):2 w l lc 0, \
        '' u ($1+a):($0==1||$0==3?$2:NaN):($0==3?7:6) w p pt var lc 0
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

A variation with shorter and less confusing plot command, but using 4 columns together with variable pointtype. This will give the same result as above.

**Code:**

```
### Heaviside function
reset session

$Heaviside <<EOD
-2 0    NaN  NaN
 0 0    6    6
 
 0 0.5  NaN  7
 
 0 1    7    6
 2 1    NaN  NaN
EOD

set yrange [-1:2]
set ytics 1
unset key
set multiplot layout 3,1
    plot $Heaviside u 1:2 w l lc 0, \
         '' u 1:2:3 w p pt var lc 0

    plot $Heaviside u 1:2 w l lc 0, \
         '' u 1:2:4 w p pt var lc 0

    set xrange [0:4]
    a = 3
    plot $Heaviside u ($1+a):2 w l lc 0, \
         '' u ($1+a):2:3 w p pt var lc 0
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Addition 2:**

In order to finalize the answer, here is an approach to plot *functions* containing the Heaviside function.
Instead of plotting from a datablock with fixed x-values (as in the two examples above) it uses the current x-range. Note, for example the syntax `plot '+' u 1:(sin($1))` is basically identical with `plot sin(x)`.

Apparently, setting the line color via `lc rgb -1` does not plot a line, which can be used here to interrupt the line. You may want to increase the samples, e.g. `set samples 300` to avoid a gap between the points and the function.

**Code:**

```
### plotting Heaviside function and functions containing Heaviside function 
#   including line interruption and inclusion/exclusion points
reset session

Heaviside(x,a) = x<a ? 0 : 1                              # definition of Heaviside function
array Hpoints[2] = [6,7]                                  # array for plotting "Heaviside points"
Hcolor(x) = (x0=x1, x1=x, x0<a && x1>=a ? -1 : 0xff0000)  # set color -1 for line interruption
dx(n) = 1e-3*(2*n-1)                                      # small dx to get y-value of points close to break

f(x,a) = 50/(x**2+2)*cos(4*x) * Heaviside(x,a)

unset key
set multiplot layout 2,1
    a = 2.0
    set yrange[-1:2]
    plot x1=NaN '+' u 1:(Heaviside(x,a)):(Hcolor(x)) w l lc rgb var, \
         Hpoints u (a):(Heaviside($1,a)):(Hpoints[$0+1]) w p pt var lc rgb Hcolor(NaN)
    
    a= 0
    set samples 300
    set yrange[-25:35]
    plot x1=NaN '+' u 1:(f(x,a)):(Hcolor(x)) w l lc rgb var, \
         Hpoints u (a):(f(a+dx($0),a)):(Hpoints[$0+1]) w p pt var lc rgb Hcolor(NaN)
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I created the following datafile (mind the two empty lines):

```
-2 0 0 1
0 0 2 1


0 0 0 1
```

and ran the following gnuplot commands:

```
set yrange [-2:2]
plot "file"     using 1:2 with lines,\
     ""         using 3:4 with lines, \
     "" index 1 using 1:2 with points pointtype 6, \
     "" index 1 using 3:4 with points pointtype 7
```

Fix the colours to your liking.

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain the relationship between the data and the plot? I'm used to just two columns for x and y.

Comment: There are four columns, the `using` tells gnuplot what columns to select for a particular plot. Two empty lines separate blocks (indexed by `index`).